# ARIMA forecast inverted

Tags: statsmodels, arima

Im using statsmodels to fit an ARIMA in python. However the forecast values are getting inverted after integrating, could anyone point what I am doing wrong?

Differencing the series for stationarity

```
          ts['val_diff1'] = ts.Value - ts.Value.shift(1)
```

Fitting a ARIMA model

```
          model2 = sm.tsa.ARIMA(ts.val_diff1.dropna(inplace=False), order=(4, 0, 4))  
          results2 = model2.fit(disp=-1)
```

Transforming fitted values back with integrating to get fitted values(un-difference)

```
          ts['frc2'] = np.r_[(ts['Value'].iloc[0]),results2.fittedvalues].cumsum()
```

However I am getting inverted forecast.

```
        [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCKfl.png
```